# How can I integrate Unity APP And Ionic

Tags: ionic-framework, unityscript, unity-game-engine

I have one question how can i integrate unity app into my ionic project?

Can I deploy unity as a webservice?

Can I deploy unity as a webapp and use in ionic?

How can I pass data from Ionic to unity app .

How can I integarte both?

Is there any way to integrate unity app in ionic?

Please help me to solve this problem

Comment: Check out http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/1223790/integration-with-ionic-framework.html

Answer (score 1):

Strange question (why you need Ionic? Can't you just relay on Unity UI features for your app?)... anyway I think that the easiest way to include an unity game in a html 5 framework like ionic is to make a webgl deploy (https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/webgl-building.html) and include it in a "webview".

However it seems that this won't work out of the box in Android, since WebGL is not natively supported by the standard webview as reported here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25702229/267719 (but the same author of the answer suggests an alternative webview using https://github.com/crosswalk-project/cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview)

If you have to communicate between unity app/game and the browser/ionic, read here: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/webgl-interactingwithbrowserscripting.html

Comment: Thanks for your reply..In this webgl I am not able pass parameter to unity..Is there any way to pass the parameter ionic to unity or Is there any other way to integrate unity with ionic ?

Comment: Unity UI is way less featured and more work than the web for any non-trivial UI.